# C++ - Do not understand the syntax of the catch function in try-catch

Tags: c++, exception

I've been learning about the `try-catch` block in C++ and I don't understand the syntax of the `catch` function.  On cppreference, it says the following:

1) To declare a formal parameter in the catch clause:

```
catch (const std::exception& e) { /* */ }
```

2) To declare an unnamed parameter:

```
catch (const std::exception&) { /* */ }
```

3) To write a "catch-all handler" (**not sure what this means**), which is activated for any exception:

```
catch (...) { /* */ }
```

**Questions:**

1) What is the difference between these `catch` blocks?  I'm not sure how a formal parameter, unnamed parameter, and a "catch-all handler" differ.

2)  What type is the parameter `e` of the `catch` clause?  Is it of type `exception`? I've never seen this type used other than in examples on how to write a `try-catch` block. If so, how could I use it in a `catch` clause to, let's say, output an error message?  Can `e` accept a string I've sent in when I throw an error?

3)  I've experimented and written a `try-catch` block as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

try
{
    throw invalid_argument("Error, program stopped.");
}

catch(const string& e)
{
    cout << e;
}
```

This code successfully calls the `catch` block and prints my message: `"Error, program stopped."`.  However, the .exe suddenly stops working and crashes.  I don't know if this is normal when an exception is thrown, or if my code is bad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
catch (const std::exception& e) { /* */ }
```

You need to use a named exception if you want to be able to access the exception object in the catch block. For example if you wanted to print `e.what()`.

```
catch (const std::exception&) { /* */ }
```

You can use an un-named exception if you don't need to access the exception object. Maybe you don't care about the contents of the exception, and you just want to handle all exceptions (of this type) in the same way.

```
catch (...) { /* */ }
```

C++ allows you to throw an object of any type, whether or not it is of a type derived from `std::exception`. This type of catch block will catch anything thrown. Just like the un-named exception, you will not have access to the thrown object. But also, you won't even have any way to know what type it is.

For your final example, I don't think it is your catch block that is printing the message. After all, you're catching the wrong type. Some compilers will automatically insert exception catching code that will catch anything that escapes main, and if it is a type derived from `std::exception`, it will print the result of `what()`, before terminating the program. I believe GCC does this, but Visual Studio does not. Not sure about Clang or any other compilers.

Comment: Thanks - I changed my code to have "exception" instead of "string" as the catch parameter, and then e.what() was able to access the string literal I sent to catch.  I use GCC so it makes sense the program ran with my old code.